# Error exporting to "Word" - Winform application - ReportViewer - vs 2010

Tags: winforms, report-viewer2010, export-to-word

I am using the reportviewer control in vs 2010 . 
I am showing my report in a winform application.

The report display itself fine but the option :
 " Export to Word " - ain't working .

I am getting the following Error :

```
" An error occurred during local report processing . 
Index is out of bounds of the array "
```

I don't know what i have done wrong .

it is important to mention - I have no drillthrough definitions in my report.

Please help me as i am lost.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: found the problem .
if the report contains a jpg picture - it will give you this error.
2 ways to make this problem go away : 
1. delete the picture.
2. convert it to png :
 - by adding a function to report code ( report >> properties >> code ) .
 - add the picture in the first place as a png.